# MathJax and Server

Tags: javascript, html, http, mathjax

Is it really necessary to serve my html through a HTTP server for mathjax to work?

I used these:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
...
...
...
...<div>\( A \over B^3 \)
...
...
```

There are no errors on the console, but I cannot seem to render the above equation.

Do I need to serve the HTML through an HTTP Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using proper link to the latest version of the library:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax TeX Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
When \(a \ne 0\), there are two solutions to: \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$
</body>
</html>
```

### Use HTTPS

In this example, you can see that I am using [HTTPS URL](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html#using-the-mathjax-content-delivery-network-cdn): `https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML` while you were using `https://cdn.mathjax.org/...`.

The reason why you should prefer HTTPS is because `MathJax` is using some script to convert your Latex into SVG, it is just safer to download these scripts from a reliable source. Also, Javascript REPLs like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), will not let you reference libraries through HTTP!

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.